# Redirect for S3 bucket from SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a couple of functions that create 2 buckets on S3, one for example.com and the other for www.example.com.  I need to know what I should use to enable the second bucket so that it will redirect to the first one.

[example of how to set it in the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K98sW.png)

My problem is I need to be able to do this using the SDK.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need to do this with the SDK, just out of curiosity? It's an easy change just by logging in, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: I am creating 1000 buckets, so I would rather just have the sdk do it when each function executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant API call is [`AWS.S3.putBucketWebsite`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketWebsite-property).

Relevant portion from the docs:

```
var params = {
    /** truncated **/
    RedirectAllRequestsTo: {
      HostName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
      Protocol: 'http | https'
    },
```

> Redirect — required — (map) Container for redirect information. You can redirect requests to another host, to another page, or with another protocol. In the event of an error, you can can specify a different error code to return.

Comment: Thanks @Josh Beam.  That was it.  Also, I need to pick a protocol.

Comment: @TomSchnaars, no problem. The protocol will be based on whether or not you have SSL set up for your domain (this can happen through CloudFront or at the load balancer level of EC2 instances). If you're not serving your site with HTTPS, then your protocol would probably just be `http` until you set up SSL.